# What is Comunication Failure in Shopware 5?

Tags: shopware

when creating new theme there's error occurred.

0 - Communication Failure

Why this happen? could you please help me?

Comment: Did you check php error log and shopware error log? Did you check `System info` in backend? http://joxi.ru/L21zEK6s8416ZA Maybe your server is poor a little bit.

Comment: Yes I do. thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens due to a timeout that occurs when the Theme-controller tries to read the Theme's configuration for the first time. Unfortunately, this is quite a resource-heavy process; on weaker servers, timeouts may occur during this process quite often.

You can confirm this by opening the Theme-Manager, opening your browser's developer tools, refreshing the Theme overview and look at the response of the `backend/Themes/list`-Request.

You can give your server more time with the php-function [set_time_limit](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php). In `engine/Shopware/Components/Theme/Installer.php`, in the `synchronize`-method, prepend `set_time_limit(0)`:

```
public function synchronize()
{
    set_time_limit(0);
    $this->synchronizeThemes();
}
```

Alternatively, prepend `set_time_limit(0);` to your `shopware.php` file, but don't forget to remove it again once the theme-overview loaded successfully.

Comment: can also be usefull to up the ajax timeout if you encounter this in theme manager > refresh themes aswell ;)